# How can I disable logs for the jmeter test running in Blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am running jmeter tests in blazemeter and in the blazemeter I see artifacts.zip and other log files created which contain all the tests details. How can I disable them and make sure these log files don't generate in blazemeter? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

BlazeMeter uses [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) under the hood so if you don't want the logs you can amend [CSV file content configuration](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#CSV-file-content-configuration) and remove the metrics you don't need.

The same is for [JMeter Test Log](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Test-Log)

More information: [BlazeMeter Logs Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261977460881-Logs-Report)